# Codigniter set_radio

Tags: php, codeigniter

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему,из базы получаю значение YES или NO для радио и мне надо radio на радио с таким же значеним повесить checked.Если создавать сам радио через form_radio то проблема реашаема.А если вот как у меня уже готовый ХТМЛ как можно реализовать подскажите пожалуйста!

```
<label class="">
   <input class="input_flat" type="radio" name="transaction_commission_split" value="yes">Yes</label>
   <label><input class="input_flat" type="radio" name="transaction_commission_split" value="no" > NO</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть контроллер Mypage.php с примерно таким кодом:

```
    public function index() {
      $db_data = $this->my_model->get_something();// предположим, что возвращается ассоциативный массив {"transaction_commission_split":"YES", "another_value":42}
      if ($db_data["transaction_commission_split"] == "Yes" ) {
        $db_data["checked_yes"] = " checked='true'";
      } else {
        $db_data["checked_no"] = " checked='true'";
      }
      $data["db_data"] =  $db_data; 
      $data["header"] = "Привет, мир!";
      $this->load->view('mypage/index', $data);
    }
```

и есть модель mypage/index.php:

```
<body>
  <h1><?=$header;?></h1>
<p>Ответ на все вопросы: <?=$db_data["another_value"];?></p>
  <input type="radio" name="transaction_commission_split" value="yes" <?=$db_data["checked_yes"];?> >Yes
  <input type="radio" name="transaction_commission_split" value="no" <?=$db_data["checked_no"];?> >No
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо я тоже разобрался,но чуток по другому.Ваш вариант покрасивее смотрится.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="">
     <input class="input_flat" type="radio" name="transaction_commission_split" value="yes" <?php echo set_radio('transaction_commission_split','yes',$commission['transaction_commission_split'] == 'yes' ? true : false);?>>Yes</label>
<label>
     <input class="input_flat" type="radio" name="transaction_commission_split" value="no" <?php echo set_radio('transaction_commission_split','no',$commission['transaction_commission_split'] == 'no' ? true : false);?>>NO</label>
```